# Design: Re-use QProcess instance, or instantiate again?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, qt, process

I have an application that issues LOTS of command-line operations (e.g., at the "console"), from different threads.  For this I'm using `QProcess` (Qt C++):

```
  QProcess* p = new QProcess();
  // ...maybe set QProcessEnvironment, set up stdout/stderr, etc....
  p->start("cmd.exe");
  p->write("dir\n");
  p->closeWriteChannel();
  p->waitForBytesWritten(-1/*forever*/);
  p->waitForReadyRead(-1/*forever*/);
  p->waitForFinished(-1/*forever*/);
  // ...read all text from process
```

The above works fine.  I could not get it to work properly under any permutation without `QProcess::closeWriteChannel()`, but I'd be interested if anyone is aware of an option (see below).

My understanding is that since I called `QProcess::closeWriteChannel()`, I can never re-open that channel.  However, since I went through the work of instantiating the `QProcess` and setting the `QProcessEnvironment`, I could merely start the process again (which re-opens the write-channel).

```
// ...after previous run:
p->start("cmd.exe");
// ...use it again...
```

This works fine too.

So, I'm comparing TWO design options:

1. **Instantiate `QProcess` each time.**  No re-use beyond a single command-line invocation.  Simple.
2. **Re-use `QProcess`.**  Do the work of "remembering" which `QProcess` instance has which `QProcessEnvironment` already set-up, so I can run commands in the appropriate environment.  Faster (no re-instantiation of `QProcess`, no re-set-up of `QProcessEnvironment()`), but requires more "book-keeping".

**QUESTION:  How significant is the runtime overhead for instantiating `QProcess` and setting up the `QProcessEnvironment`?**

Significant?  I need to execute many thousands of command-line operations across many threads.  If it is "big", that steers me towards (2) (do-able, I've figured out how).  Otherwise, (1) is really simple, and I don't want to complicate things for no reason.

Yes, *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."*  I'm not trying to do that.  This system needs to massively scale.

Thoughts?

Comment: Simple answer: measure it :) I doubt it will worth the additional complexity to reuse the QProcess instances, as creating the native processes and actually running them will create much more overhead. But a definitive answer you only get from profiling it.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>   QProcess* p = new QProcess();
>   // ...maybe set QProcessEnvironment, set up stdout/stderr, etc....
>   p->start("cmd.exe");
>   p->write("dir\n");
>   p->closeWriteChannel();
>   p->waitForBytesWritten(-1/*forever*/);
>   p->waitForReadyRead(-1/*forever*/);
>   p->waitForFinished(-1/*forever*/);
>   // ...read all text from process
> ```
>
> The above works fine. I could not get it to work properly under any
> permutation without QProcess::closeWriteChannel(), but I'd be
> interested if anyone is aware of an option (see below).

Currently you are writing "\n" as to characters.
You need to write them as a single character.

```
p->write(QString("dir") + '\n');
```

instead of

```
p->write("dir\n");
p->closeWriteChannel();
```

With this method the write channel stays open and you can react should the process query for input.